# Create dataframe from rows under a row with a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an ugly data source that I am trying to clean up. I cannot make the source cleaner, I receive it like this. I am using Python and Pandas dataframes. The first column contains a cell with a datetime object followed by several cells with string, and then another datetime object, and then more strings. The number of strings is not known.

I would like to make each group of data into its own dataframe, so that I may export each group neatly into separate sheets in a spreadsheet, which is required for this project.

so, input dataframe has a first column something like this:

```
df[col1]
-----
datetime.datetime.strptime('06/23/2021', "%m/%d/%Y")
'tony'
'nikki'
'james'
datetime.datetime.strptime('06/24/2021', "%m/%d/%Y")
'amy'
'jose'
datetime.datetime.strptime('06/25/2021', "%m/%d/%Y")
'tony'
'jose'
'eddie'
'anna'
```

And I would like to split it into several dataframes like this:

```
df1[col1]
-----
'tony'
'nikki'
'james'

df2[col1]
-----
'amy'
'jose'

df3[col1]
-----
'tony'
'jose'
'eddie'
'anna'
```

I am not sure how to go about it, without just iterating through the rows, which I understand to be a last resort approach while using pandas.

iterating through the rows would be something like (this is pseudo code as this is part of my struggle)

```
strRows = []
dfs = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    
    while row not contain datetime object:
        # append row to list to add to new dataframe
        strRows.append(row)
    # create new dataFrame with saved rows
    newDF = pd.DataFrame(strRows)
    dfs.append(newDF)
```

Although ultimately I'd like to preserve the date information and name the new dataframe after that date, for now I am just concerned with extracting the rows.

My question: Is `df.iterrows()` a good way to go about this, or is there a non-iterative approach that is preferential?

I appreciate any advice. Thanks.

### EDIT:

Based on advice here, and more general churning, I ended up creating a new column that contained the date itself, this way.

```
df["Day"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'], errors='coerce').fillna(method='ffill')
```

The `errors='coerce'` makes an error in parsing result in an ' NaT', and the `fillna(method='ffill')` makes the date fill in the whole column. This is important specifically because Col1 contains datetimes and strings, so when `to_datetime` encounters a string, I want it to give a `NaT`, so that the `fillna` can use the `ffill` to fill in the datetimes down the line.

Then, since my ultimate goal was actually to create sheets in a spreadsheet, not separate dataframes, I used a dictionary created by a groupby to write to my xlsx directly.

```
df_days = {key: value for (key, value) in df.groupby('Day')}

with writer as writer:
    for key in df_days:
        df_days[key].to_excel(writer, key, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure I saw a similar case recently but couldn't find it.. There's probably a better solution, but here's one option that makes a new column that accumulates a counter you can use to split the data using `groupby`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# make a test df
data = [datetime.datetime.strptime('06/23/2021', "%m/%d/%Y"),
'tony',
'nikki',
...]

df = pd.DataFrame({"raw":data})

# basically count +1 every time a datetime object is encountered
df["groups"] = df.raw.apply(isinstance, args=(datetime.datetime,)).astype(int).cumsum()
```

Result:

```py
                    raw  groups
0   2021-06-23 00:00:00       1
1                  tony       1
2                 nikki       1
3                 james       1
4   2021-06-24 00:00:00       2
5                   amy       2
6                  jose       2
7   2021-06-25 00:00:00       3
8                  tony       3
9                  jose       3
10                eddie       3
11                 anna       3
```

Then you can get the individual groups via `df.groupby("groups")`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to do it with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), backended by pandas, but implements dplyr-like syntax:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> from datar.all import (
...     f, tibble, grepl, cumsum, tail,
...     select, mutate, group_modify, group_split, group_by, 
... )
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     col1=[
...         datetime.datetime.strptime('06/23/2021', "%m/%d/%Y"),
...         'tony',
...         'nikki',
...         'james',
...         datetime.datetime.strptime('06/24/2021', "%m/%d/%Y"),
...         'amy',
...         'jose',
...         datetime.datetime.strptime('06/25/2021', "%m/%d/%Y"),
...         'tony',
...         'jose',
...         'eddie',
...         'anna',
...     ]
... )
>>> df
                   col1
               <object>
0   2021-06-23 00:00:00
1                  tony
2                 nikki
3                 james
4   2021-06-24 00:00:00
5                   amy
6                  jose
7   2021-06-25 00:00:00
8                  tony
9                  jose
10                eddie
11                 anna

>>> dfs = df >> mutate(
...     # or your way to identify the datetime value
...     is_date=grepl("00:00:00", f.col1),
...     # group the datetime and the following values
...     group=cumsum(f.is_date)
... ) >> group_by(
...     f.group
... ) >> select(
...     # don't include the intermediate column
...     ~f.is_date
... ) >> group_modify(
...     # exclude the first row
...     lambda df: tail(df, -1)
... ) >> group_split()
>>> # dfs is a generator
>>> list(dfs)
[    group     col1
  <int64> <object>
0       1     tony
1       1    nikki
2       1    james,     group     col1
  <int64> <object>
3       2      amy
4       2     jose,     group     col1
  <int64> <object>
5       3     tony
6       3     jose
7       3    eddie
8       3     anna]

>>> _[0] # take a look at the first df
    group     col1
  <int64> <object>
0       1     tony
1       1    nikki
2       1    james
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that `datetime.datetime.strptime...` is a string:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r"datetime.datetime.strptime\('(.*)', .*").ffill()
df = df[~df['col1'].str.contains('datetime')]

       col1        col2
1    'tony'  06/23/2021
2   'nikki'  06/23/2021
3   'james'  06/23/2021
5     'amy'  06/24/2021
6    'jose'  06/24/2021
8    'tony'  06/25/2021
9    'jose'  06/25/2021
10  'eddie'  06/25/2021
11   'anna'  06/25/2021
```

Then use `df.groupby('col2')` to do further processing leveraging `'col2'` to name your `dataframe` for each group.